# Golang context switch

Tags: multithreading, go, operating-system

I have a very basic doubt:
Can OS scheduler context switch between User level threads mapped to kernel level?

Lets say goscheduler scheduled a goroutine A on the kernal thread. Now goroutine A makes sysblock call, who will context switch first: OS or go scheduler?

Comment: This is not defined and depends on the Go version, the Go compiler and the OS. (It also is pretty unactionable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go scheduler manages goroutines, which are multiplexed onto OS-level threads. The Go scheduler can efficiently perform context switches between goroutines, such as when a goroutine makes a blocking system call, without necessarily involving the OS scheduler. However, it's important to note that the OS scheduler may independently interrupt and perform context switches due to factors like time slicing. Therefore, the exact timing of context switches and the involvement of the OS scheduler may not be precisely determined from the perspective of a Go program.

For further reading:

[proc.go in golang source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/proc.go)

[Go scheduler: Implementing language with lightweight concurrency](https://youtu.be/-K11rY57K7k)